# TCP Outgoing Connection w. Docker-NodeRed

Tags: docker, node-red, synology

first of all, I have to mention that I am a complete rookie in Docker and NodeRed :) I have a KNX visualization server running and want to establish a TCP connection with NodeRed. My NodeRed is running in a docker container on my Synology.

My flow looks like this:

[image: NodeRed Echo Flow]

The flow is waiting for an incoming "Hallo" message and if so should return "Hallo Welt". The incoming side is working fine but I get no outgoing connection.

Now I don't know if the problem is within Docker, NodeRed or my visualization server. Both NodeRed and the server show the connection as established. I can receive a message "Hallo" and the flow wants to send out "Hallo Welt", but I do not receive any message on the KNX server.

I set the TCP in node to listen on port 1338 and the out node to "answer on TCP". The KNX server is a TCP client connecting to the Synology IP with the port set in Docker. In my case, I map 49157 (automatically generated) to 1338.

Now I know that this post is weirdly written, I am sorry for me being a German guy writing in English while still thinking in German :D

Comment: Have you tried testing it with something other than KNX? e.g. running `telnet ip 49157` And do you get output from all the debug nodes? (The test inject will not work because it won't have a valid `session` value to use for the reply) Also the little red triangle implies that the TCP-response node is not configured properly)

Comment: I don't know why there's a little triangle, maybe I have made the screenshot while testing another configuration, right now with the tcp out node as "answer to tcp" there is no triangle but the note that the connection is not right. Output:
'15.4.2022, 11:34:23node: TCP
msg.payload : buffer[5]
[ 72, 97, 108, 108, 111 ]
15.4.2022, 11:34:24node: Payload ist Hallo
msg : Object
{ topic: "", payload: buffer[5], ip: "::ffff:172.17.0.1", port: 33436, _session: object … }
15.4.2022, 11:34:24node: Senden
msg.payload : string[10]
"Hallo Echo"'

Comment: When using putty I get the answer back. In NodeRed:
'15.4.2022, 11:38:03node: TCP
msg.payload : buffer[7]
[ 72, 97, 108, 108, 111, 13, 10 ]
15.4.2022, 11:38:03node: Payload ist Hallo
msg : Object
{ topic: "", payload: buffer[7], ip: "::ffff:172.17.0.1", port: 33583, _session: object … }
15.4.2022, 11:38:03node: Senden
msg.payload : string[10]
"Hallo Echo"'

So it seems like the problem is on the KNX Server side ...

Comment: This is not a programming question